# Connect iPhone to a Web Service?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

New to iPhone development and working through exercises and examples to get me up to speed. Does anyone have a good reference for connecting an iPhone app to a website/webservice and push/pull data?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018369/accessing-web-service-from-iphone

Comment: the most asked question for iphone dev here in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked for me:  [SOAP/web services](http://icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)

Answer (score 2):

I have not used [Core Resource](http://coreresource.org/) yet, but it may be what you're looking for. It claims to provide (from the project's front page):

1. Easy querying into a webservice, e.g.:

   ```
   [Note findAll:$D(@"Buster", @"author", @"createdAt DESC", @"$sort")];
   ```
2. Automatic serialization of returned results into a Core Data context
3. Easy resource-based tables using `CoreTableController`, e.g.:

   ```
   [self fetchForRelatedResource:parent withSort:@"lastName ASC"];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wsdl file of the service you can use an [automatic tool](http://www.wsdl2code.com) to build your service proxy and all the needed code in seconds.

```
SampleServiceProxy *proxy = [[SampleServiceProxy alloc]initWithUrl:@"YOUR
        URL" AndDelegate:self];
[proxy GetDouble];
[proxy GetEnum];
[proxy getEnum:kTestEnumTestEnum2];
[proxy GetInt16];
[proxy GetInt32];
[proxy GetInt64];
[proxy GetString];
[proxy getListStrings];
```